# Code not executing after db.each() (nodejs-sqlite3)

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, node-sqlite3

1 is being logged
2 is being logged
3 isn't logged which means that the code after db.each isn't working somehow, can someone help please?

```
  var db = new sqlite3.Database("database.sqlite")
  console.log("2")
  db.each("SELECT * FROM gban WHERE id = '"+id+"'", async function(err, row) {
    console.log("3")
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(row)
    if(row != undefined){
     // code
    }
    if(row == undefined){
    // code
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's explained [in the fine manual](https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#eachparam---callback--complete):

> If the result set succeeds but is empty, the callback is never called.

You can also pass a third argument to `db.each()`, which should be a function that gets called when `db.each()` has completed.